# google transliterate vs translate api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

We want to transliterate sentences from English to Hindi using google cloud services or any other similar/scaled platform.

Currently we started using google translate as its transliterate api is deprecated now.

But the issue is, its translating it basis actual sentiments that we don't want:

Example:

```
English (Lemon Tree) ---google translate in hindi--- नींबू का पेड़
```

What we intend for our use case is :

```
English (Lemon Tree) ---google translate in hindi--- लेमन ट्री
```

Is there any workaround in current translation api to get transliteration or any better/stable , similar cost api which we can use for solving this use case.

**Api Sources :**

Currently getting used : https://cloud.google.com/translate/
Deprecated but working well: https://developers.google.com/transliterate/

Answer (score 6):

An easy workaround if you want to use Google cloud translation api,  is to pass :
`(My name is "YOUR_TEXT_HERE")`
as input to google Cloud Translation API and that will give you desired **transliterated** text inside double quotes "...". Then you can extract out your transliteration that is within " ".

In your example:
Pass Input: `(My name is "Lemon Tree")`
Output: `(मेरा नाम "लेमन ट्री" है)`

NOTE: This will unnecessarily increase your character count and hence your service bill.

Comment: that's genius!!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any alternative APIs for the deprecated transliterate. You can play with google translation modes, that might improve the quality of translation for short phrases. For example:

```
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/?q=lemon%20tree&source=en&target=hi&model=base&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
```

The `model=base` part tells that you want to use the Phrase-Based Machine Translation (PBMT) model.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Caner, i tried it with all models that google supports, and it still works that way.

Answer (score 2):

pip install googletrans

code -

```
  from googletrans import Translator 

  my_input= ("I am very happy to be here with you today to receive the Nobel Prize 
  for Peace.")

  print(my_input)

  translator = Translator()

  translated_txt=translator.translate(my_input, dest='hi').text
  print(translated_txt)

  transliterated_txt=translator.translate(translated_txt, dest='hi').pronunciation
  print(transliterated_txt)
```

The following code will produce this output-

I am very happy to be here with you today to receive the Nobel Prize for Peace.

शांति के लिए नोबेल पुरस्कार प्राप्त करने के लिए मैं आज आपके साथ यहां आकर बहुत खुश हूं।

shaanti ke lie nobel puraskaar praapt karane ke lie main aaj aapake saath yahaan aakar bahut khush hoon.

So you can still use Google pronunciation to **transliterate** the **Hindi text into English**, not sure about the transliteration other way round, may be you can play with googletrans to get that done as well

Comment: Your example is that of a **Translation** and NOT a **Transliteration** . Transliteration doesn't change sentence structure and doesn't takes context into account, it simply replaces the letters with closest equivalent in letter set of the target language.  Example "  मेरा नाम अंकित हे" transliterated to English is "mera naam ankit he" and NOT " My name is Ankit" , which would have been a translation.

Answer (score 0):

Literal translation is basically translating the meaning of the words and not the phrase as a whole. So you can achieve that by getting word by word translation and then just concatenating them together. So if you translate "lemon" then "tree" and add the results together, you should get what you are looking for.

Using Google Translate, I found that the word for "Lemon" is नींबू and the word for "Tree' is पेड़.

So the literal, word for word translation would be नींबू पेड़ .

Also, the deprecated API can still be used if you want, read the [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/terms) first. In the mean time, you can also file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187144&template=0) with Google's Public Issue Tracker to get this feature in Google Translate API.

Comment: Initial plan was that only @Ying and we tries doing that as well. But it is not working way we expect. It works as i mentioned in the question even after splitting in words .

Comment: Really? But doesn't that mean the translation is correct? I don't see how splitting up the words would result in a contextual translation instead of a literal one.

If I simply tell Translate API to translate "cool", it will give the temperature reference... Only in context of say "cool person" would it use a different meaning.

Per word translation should be by definition literal, there's no context to it.

Comment: My point is, even if you split work lemon & tree and translate them independently, they will still result into lemon- > नींबू and for Tree it would be पेड़...ideally this should have been लेमन for Lemon and ट्री for tree

Comment: I see what you mean now. Unfortunately, Google Translate doesn't work that way (it only translate by meaning not pronunciation). As I mentioned, you would need to use the deprecated API or file a feature request to get this feature in Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Transliterate API in Python, first do:
`pip install google-transliteration-api`

Sample script to transliterate:

```py
from google.transliteration import transliterate_text
result = transliterate_text('Lemon Tree', lang_code='hi')
print(result) # Output: 'लेमन ट्री'
```

For more details, check the [documentation here](https://pypi.org/project/google-transliteration-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate API officially supports transliteration, so no hack is required. Please refer this documentation - https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#transliteration

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Punit Pandey, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)